# Query DbContext during OnModelCreating for tenantId filtering

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am using .NET Core 5 with Entity Framework Core. I already have soft deletes by using `SetQueryFilters` with `ActiveId` to act as a delete.

I also want to apply a filter for certain tables that have a `TenantId` column to only show records that match the current user's organizations they are a part of (where `TenantId` falls within a list of `OrganizationId`s). I have the following code

```
public partial class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public AppContext (DbContextOptions<AppContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    #region Generated Properties
    ...
    #endregion

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            var isActiveProperty = entityType.FindProperty("ActiveId");
            var isTenantProperty = entityType.FindProperty("TenantId");

            if (isTenantProperty != null && isTenantProperty.ClrType == typeof(Int32) 
                && isActiveProperty != null && isActiveProperty.ClrType == typeof(Int32))
            {
                List<int> Ids = ///--Ids.NEEDTOGRABTHESE
                var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType.ClrType, "p");
                var filter = Expression.Lambda(
                    Expression.And(
                    Expression.OrElse(
                      Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(parameter, "ActiveId"), Expression.Constant((int)ActiveCodes.ACTIVE)),
                      Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(parameter, "ActiveId"), Expression.Constant((int)ActiveCodes.BLOCKED))
                    ),
                    Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(parameter, "TenantId"), ///--Ids.NEEDTOGRABTHESE)
                    ),
                parameter);

                entityType.SetQueryFilter(filter);//Update for ef 3.0
            }
        }
        #region Generated Configuration
        ...
        #endregion
    }
}
```

I'm struggling to find out how to query the database inside the `OnModelCreating`. I need to query the database in order to get the current users organizations. If I try to reference the context while inside `OnModelCreating`, I get the following error:

> An attempt was made to use the model while it was being created. A DbContext instance cannot be used inside 'OnModelCreating' in any way that makes use of the model that is being created.

Since the only way I can access the current users organization is by accessing the database, and the dbContext is inaccessible at this point, what can I do to access the dbContext during the `OnModelCreating`?

Also if you suggest something is it efficient enough to be called every time `OnModelCreating` is built (would it cache the response)?

Comment: .NET 5 is out of support (or soon will be, if not already). You ought to upgrade to .NET 6.

Comment: Thanks, I agree but our server currently doesn't support .NET 6. We are pushing to do so, but I think there should be a solution that exists over both versions. I'm just kind of new to entity framework.

Comment: You cannot use EF Core query methods during `OnModelCreating` - `Model` is not initialized and EF Core can do almost nothing.

Comment: You can define property `TenantId` in `DbContext`, create filter against this property. In property getter of `TenantId` - do any query which you want or assign this property before querying database.

Comment: It's kind of illogical. Because when you log in, context is created and OnModelCreate is fired already. So, you need to obtain that TenantId without using the context as far as I understand.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your requirement correctly, you need to use HasQueryFilter API.

ex:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Organization>().HasQueryFilter(org => org.UserId == _userId);
```

here is the link, for a better explanation. Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another context for Tenants. The solution you are looking for is here:

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57537225/queryfilter-on-applicationuser-in-onmodelcreating-in-applicationdbcontext-create)